# How do you make a Video File Texture in 2.81?

Tags: texturing, video

I cannot seem to find any updated information on this.

I am trying to make a plane that is a video file.  For the life of me I cannot figure out how.  I applied the video file as a texture, set the amount of frames and the start frame, but all that Blender will show is the first frame of the video.  It will not play it.

All I can find about this is old out dated tutorials.  I follow them as best I can considering the UI is totally different now, but nothing seems to work.

Every video file I try just shows the first frame and that is it.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Using Cycles Render Engine

Here is my node set up:
[image]

Comment: Added node set up.  Cycles Render Engine

Comment: Enable Auto Refresh

Comment: THANK YOU!!! That was what I was missing

Answer (score 1):

Enable Auto Refresh in the image texture node [image]